LaplaceTransform and DSolve handles PDE well in version 14, but not in 13.3
I'm facing an error when trying to solve a simple Laplace-transformed PDE with one basic boundary condition, followed by applying the InverseLaplaceTransform. The issue doesn't occur in Mathematica version 14.1 but exists in version 13. I'm using version 13 because version 14.1 has a bug, you can refer to my previous question for details about the bug I encountered.
Code:
(* Step 1: Define the PDE *)
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D * D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];

(* Step 2: Laplace Transform the PDE with respect to t *)
pdeLaplace = LaplaceTransform[pde, t, s];

(* Step 3: Replace the Laplace Transform with U[x, s] *)
pdeLaplace = pdeLaplace /. LaplaceTransform[u[x, t], t, s] -> U[x, s];

(* Step 4: Solve the PDE in the Laplace domain *)
solutionLaplace = DSolve[{pdeLaplace, U[0, s] == 0, U[L, s] == 0}, U[x, s], x];

(* Step 5: Apply the Inverse Laplace Transform *)
solutionTimeDomain = InverseLaplaceTransform[U[x, s] /. solutionLaplace[[1]], s, t];

(* Display the solution *)
solutionTimeDomain // TraditionalForm

Output:

Any advice?

You cannot use D as a constant. Avoid single capital letters C,D,E,I,.

Can you please clarify what you are attempting to define in your “Step 1”? It appears you are using the D function incorrectly with respect to the term on the RHS.

First of all, as pointed out by comments above, it's not a good idea to use D as variable name. Then, you've actually provided two boundary conditions when solving the PDE i.e. U[0, s] == 0, U[L, s] == 0. These aren't relevant to the issue here, though.
The root of issue is strongly related to the bug you've encountered in your previous question. In v14.0 LaplaceTransform has got a new feature silently:
LaplaceTransform[D[u[t, x], x], t, s]


As we can see, the Derivative has been transformed to a D and taken out of LaplaceTransform. This isn't the behavior in earlier versions:

It's not hard to notice the new-added feature will facillitate symbolic PDE solving, if it's bug free.
"OK, then how do you guys handle the PDE in earlier versions?" We just need a cleverer replacement rule:
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == \[ScriptCapitalD] D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
pdeLaplace = 
 LaplaceTransform[pde, t, s] /. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, t, s] :> (a /. u -> (U[#, s] &))


Remark

It's worth pointing out that, the replacement /. u -> (U[#, s] &) makes the output easier to read, but isn't necessary for programming. We can omit it and simply keep in mind that u[x, t] inside pdeLaplace stands for $U(x,s)$.

There exist many examples solving PDE with LaplaceTransform in this site, have a search.



Can you suggest me some posts that have good examples?

@ali Just search with proper keywords and rank them by score: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdifferential-equations%5d%20%20laplacetransform&searchOn=3
